# OAuth2 WebAuthenticationBroker in Windows Phone does not callback to ContinuationManager

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, windows-phone-8.1, continuations

I'm doing OAuth2 authentication in my Windows Phone 8.1 app and I'm using the `WebAuthenticationBroker` with the `AuthenticateAndContinue()` method for WP.
I'm authenticating to my server where I send two parameters and it returns my access token, without any other step in and between. Given this situation I don't have a callbakUri, so I use the `WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri()`
My code looks like this:

```
Uri endpointURL = new Uri(_requestUrl + "&client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret);
Uri callbackUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(endpointURL, callbackUri, null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);
```

I have the `ContinuationManager.cs` class in my project, as well as all the changed needed in the `App.xaml.cs`, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631755.aspx
My problem is that after I execute the code above, the `Continue()` method in the `ContinuationManager` class is never executed, so my app blocks there.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't know what service your are calling, but it probably expects the callback URI in one of the parameters (along with the client id and client secret). Otherwise, there's no way it could guess where it needs to redirect the user after authentication

Comment: That's the thing, it doesn't. I can make the request by an HTTP POST instead, but it would be nice to use new class.

Comment: What is the value of `_requestUrl` ?

Comment: Please explain "it would be nice to use new class". You have a new screwdriver, and you want to use it to drive a nail into the wall? If you can make the request with a POST request, then why don't you? See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue` knows the authentication is done when the user is redirected to a specific page.

There's two way to deal with it:

1. Most services accept a parameter to set the URI the user is redirected to (the parameter is often called `callback`. In that case, you can generate an URI with `WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri` and pass it to the `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue` method (as you're doing in your code sample)
2. If the service doesn't accept a callback parameter, then you need to do things the other way: first check what URI the service redirects too (by calling it manually once), then pass this URI to the `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue` method. For instance, let's say the OAuth service redirects to http://www.stackoverflow.com, then you need to call:

   ```
   WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(endpointURL, new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com"), null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the [Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4). This is a non-interactive flow, and you do not need a WebAuthenticationBroker to use it. Just use an HttpClient to get the token, *if you are using this flow*.

That being said, this flow is probably not what you need. First of all, I am assuming that you do want to authenticate the actual user, a.k.a. the resource owner. Secondly, the flow you are using requires the client secret to be present in your phone application. That is a big no-no! This flow is intended for server-side processes!

I think you need to look at the [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) instead.

Comment: I am indeed using the Client Credentials Grant, and the Http approach seems now the correct one. However I think the Q&A on this topic is valid and helpful for people who may want to callback to their own service. I thank you though, for the additional and helpful answer.

Comment: @ricochete I still fail to understand why you authenticate using client credentials. If you embed the client id and client secret in your phone app, it is basically available to everyone. You might just as well not authenticate. Can you explain?

Comment: The authentication will be done in a Class Library and the client data will be passed by the main app. It's requested to work like this, I don't have input on the matter.